# css modues takes a lot of time to apply to a Mui component in nextJs 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

hello i've got an issue customizing a Mui component by applying a css class, the problem is that when i refresh my page it first display default Mui components, then only after 50seconds it applies my css (i use css.modules) and i've put all my code inside app folder, what could be the issue ?

```
<AppBar position="static" className={styles.navbar}>
```

for example here, it first display a blue navbar then only after it turns red